# why can't i put an image in message box in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i want to make a button that displays a pop up message with a photo in it, but when i click it displays **"pyimage1"**

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def message():
    messagebox.showinfo("title", ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'C:\Users\EH\Pictures\cat.jpg')))


root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')
root.title("cat pic button")
button = Button(root, text="show me cute cat pic", command=message)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***it displays "pyimage1"***: The second positional argument are: `message=`, therefore you see the default name of the image. Why have you choosen the `messagabox` widget to show a image?

Comment: Also, your image is subject to garbage collection unless you keep an active reference: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm.  Follow up on what @stovfl said, you might want to use `Toplevel` instead?

Comment: it might be not supported because messagebox already shows you a predefined image - different for info, error and questions. If image supported there I would expect syntax akin to label or text widgets `image = PhotoImage('C:\Users\EH\Pictures\cat.jpg')`

Comment: I don't think if `messagebox.showinfo` support to show an *image* as these are the arguments that a `showinfo` takes **`detail`, `icon`, `message`, `parent`, `title`, `type`, or `command`** and I don't see an `image` argument to support image.

Comment: thanks for this info, i am a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did something wrong which was choosing messagebox to display a photo
i solved it by replacing the message function with this:

```
def message():
    global my_img
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("cat photo")
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'C:\Users\EH\Pictures\cat.jpg'))
    Label(top, image=my_img).pack()
```